# Storing a json string that is 10 kb in size in a SQL Server CE cell

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-ce, sqldatatypes, sql-server-ce-3.5

I have a SQL Server CE database in which I have column that takes values of json strings. These json strings are above 9kb as a result of which I am unable to use `varchar` or `char`. I guess I could tackle this through the usage of `ntext`.

But in SQL Server, this is marked to be removed in an upcoming editions. I am not sure of SQL Server CE. Also I am having where and having conditions/statements on other values stored in this column. Therefore having `ntext` may not help as well.

Are there any other data types that I could use to store this json string? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You only option is to use next, and if you need to search the text, do so using C# / LINQ to objects

Comment: There are already several queries that use where and having statements. Therefore if I change the data type to ntext it causes a lot of issues. Changing them to C#/LINQ would be a big change for now. Aren't there any other work arounds?

Comment: No, I do not know of any other workaround, forcing client evaluation should be a simple fix, adding ToList()/FirstOrDefault etc.